# How many extensions

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, extensions, magento-connect

Just trying to see if there is a easy way to get the number of extensions on Magento Connect for v1 and for v2.

From looking at https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-2
I believe there are 512 extensions for v2 but couldnt see any easy way to count how many there are for v1. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the last page with extensions on magento connect:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=1&pl=0&eb=0&hp=0&q=&t=0&p=929

There are 10 extensions per page and 9 on the last page.
So the total is `929*10 - 1 = 9289` extensions on magento connect.

Comment: Good catch on this one

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how active Triple Check has been, I know it hasn't been updated for some time but according to them: http://triplecheck.io/

There's at least 6134 free extensions (I reckon they only check free extensions).

On http://packages.firegento.com/ (which is up to date) there are 3000+ packages listed but I reckon some packages are not listed there.

Personnally, I'd say between this number and 10k but I'm not aware of another way to know.

Comment: Thanks but ideally I would quite like the total number of extensions including paid as well as free.  My first guess would be ~15000

Comment: @Goose84 In that case I'm not too sure how to process